# How to remove/uninstall mongochef?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, uninstall

So, i installed mongochef a while ago, but i didn't work quite well, but now, there is the 4.4.2 and it works well, but, i'm using that version directly from the folder, and my installed version still the previous version, so i want to know how to uninstall the older version so i can try to install the new one.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Well, how did you install it in the first place?

Comment: I followed this http://3t.io/blog/install-mongochef-mongodb-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoChef is [distributed](http://3t.io/blog/install-mongochef-mongodb-linux/) as a `.tar.gz` file and not handled by the package manager.

Therefore you can just do a `sudo rm -rf <path to old mongochef folder>` and you'll be fine.

EDIT: To find the old mongochef folder, do a

```
sudo find / -name mongochef.sh -type f
```

It will output something like

```
/your/path/old-mongochef/bin/mongochef.sh
/another/path/new-mongochef/bin/mongochef.sh
```

One is the old install, the other one is the new install. Be sure to identify correctly the old install folder.

Here your MongoChef install dir is `/your/path/old-mongochef` and you can remove it with

```
sudo rm -rf /your/path/old-mongochef
```

Comment: Ok, but, how can i find the path of the old mongo?, i mean, is some line command i can use to find it? (I tried looking in the root/bin/, but it's not there... I'm sorry, i'm very new with Ubuntu)

Comment: @SantiagoP See my edited answer.